# Preserve column names when refreshing data in Excel

Tags: excel, sharepoint, connection, rename, vba

I have an Excel sheet with a Data Connection to SharePoint 2010, to pull data from a List. (I am not using Power Query because it always failed to Authenticate with SharePoint).

My query pulls data from a view successfully, and all data is fine.

The issue is I would like to change my Column Names. (Such as from Title to Task).

I can rename them successfully from the sheet, but when I refresh the data, the headers are refreshed (and thus column names are lost).

Protecting the Sheet is not an option since it does not allow data connections to be refreshed.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select a cell in your pivot table and go to Options tab. Select Options in the PivotTable group. Make sure the "Preserve cell formatting on update" box is checked.

This should preserve any formatting on your PivotTable, including column names.

EDIT: I should have prefaced this by saying you could create a PivotTable with custom column names that would be preserved upon refresh (as an alternative to the first answer).

Ideal solution would be to rename fields when you create the view.

Comment: When creating a table from a Data Connection (using a .iqy file, in my case) from the Data Tab, Excel does not create a Pivot Table. I can create a Pivot table from my data source, but that does not present the data in a tabular form as I expect, rather it summarizes the data.

Comment: You can put the pivot table in tabular form by going to the Design tab >> Report Layout >> Tabular Form

Comment: Thanks! I followed up on this. I ended up using this procedure. The last issue is banded rows. It simply does not work out of the box. I ended up writing conditional formatting to achieve so. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can't change the underlying list's column headers for some reason, the easiest thing to do is create a new row outside of your data table and hide the data table's column headers:

1. Right click the first row label on the left and select "Insert".
2. Name your column headers what ever you want in the new row
3. Hide the old column headers by right clicking what is now the second row and selecting "Hide"

Now when you refresh the table, the column headers will remain untouched.

Comment: That's a bit hacky. The current rows are being used to filter the data..but I guess attaching it to filters MIGHT work. I'll consider this as a 'last resort'. I wanted to freeze the current data rather than hide.